# Initializing a matrix with C

Tags: c

I can't imagine a simpler case of matrix initialization, and yet it goes horribly wrong, with the program getting into an endless loop. WHY????

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void ) 
{
    int M [ 5 ] [5] = {{}} ;
    int i , j ;
    
    for ( i = 1 ; i <= 5 ; i ++ )
    {
        for ( j = 1 ; j <= 5 ; j ++ )  M [ i ] [ j ] = 1 ; 

    } 
    
    return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indexes in arrays start from zero.

So the code should be

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int M[5][5] = {{}} ;
    int i, j ;
    
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i ++ )
    {
        for (j = 0 ; j < 5 ;j ++ )  M[i][j] = 1 ; 
    } 
   
    return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not only, at stated above, indexes start with 0, not 1, which would lead you to write

```c
  for (i=0; i<5; i++)
```

… instead of :

```c
  for (i=1; i<=5; i++)
```

… (note the `<` sign instead of `<=`) but if you do it anyway, nothing will prevent you from doing. Since the machine code produced by your C compiler sticks to adding the index to the base pointer, you'll exceed the end of your array, thus leading to a **buffer overflow**.

And what lies after the array you declared are your index variables `i` and `j`. Since you fill your array with ones only, you'll write `1` into your index variables each time you run out of your array, hence resetting it to this particular value, and that's why your loop will never end.

Comment: Re “nothing will prevent you”: Writing outside array bounds may or may not result in a trap due to memory protection. Re “the machine code produced by your C compiler sticks to adding the index to the base pointer”: Optimization by the compiler may produce other results than mechanical addition of indices to array bases. Re “what lies after the array you declared are”: What lies after the array is subject to variation depending on a variety of compiler operations and optimizations and other factors.